# PHP's MemcacheD extension DLL for Windows

Tags: php, memcached, php7, compilation

On my PHP 5.6 site I have been using the [Memcache](https://pecl.php.net/package/memcache) extension to interface with the memcached daemon. As the extension has a matching DLL, it meant I could deploy it on my Windows dev machine as well and all was good.

This extension has been abandoned however, and there is no official support for PHP7. So I would like to move to the [MemcacheD](https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached) extension instead.  The problem is that I can't find any windows DLL version for this.  There is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243745/memcached-not-memcache-php-extension-on-windows) from 5 years ago on StackOverflow but nothing since that I can find.

There seem to be [no official plans](https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/71) to build a Windows DLL, but since PHP provides instructions for [how to compile one](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild#building_pecl_extensions) (beyond what I can do without help), I'm hoping someone else knows of a source compatible with PHP 7.2

Answer (score 1):

Please find php_memcache.dll for **php7.0.x, php7.1.x, php7.2.x**
https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll

- **vc14** & **vc15**
- **x86** & **x64**
- **ts** & **nts**

You can also try:
The new `memcached` extension doesn't work on Windows because `libmemcached` doesn't work on Windows. However, someone seems to have gotten the old `memcache` extension to install on Windows. I can't find a nice pre-compiled binary, but, after a lot of digging, I found a [PHP Bug Report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70751) about this issue. Someone there seems to have found a solution:

> **[2016-01-20 23:11 UTC] php at alternize dot com**
>
> the branch "NON_BLOCKING_IO_php7" of the git repository https://github.com/websupport-sk/pecl-memcache.git builds fine against php 7.0.2 in win32 x86 thread-safe mode. i have not tested it with non-thread-safe and/or x64.
>
> to build the php_memcache.dll, i followed the instructions on https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild#building_pecl_extensions using:

```
C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc14\x86\php-7.0.2-src>buildconf
C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc14\x86\php-7.0.2-src>configure --disable-all 
  --enable-cli --enable-zlib --enable-hash --enable-session 
  --without-gd --with-bz2 --enable-memcache=shared
C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc14\x86\php-7.0.2-src>nmake
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I have seen that resource and I'm actually using it with PHP 7.2 (in development, not production), but I would like to move to MemcacheD since that is being actively maintained.  What you wrote about `libmemcached` is interesting though: does it mean that `MemcacheD` on Windows just can't be done right now?

Comment: The official repo: https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached and you need libmemcached. Which is unavailable on windows. And memcached is according to his official repo: A "PHP extension for interfacing with memcached via libmemcached library". Memcache is According to his official repo: A "memcached extension"